# Is it possible to update ChromiumPortable included with Smartmeter?

Tags: jmeter, smartmeter

Is it possible to update ChromiumPortable included with SmartMeter?

I have SmartMeter 1.0.4W_Light and Downloaded ChromiumPortable version 45.0.2431.0

When I tried to install ChromiumPortable version in %SmartMeter_dir%\programs\ChromiumPortable\ the ChromiumPortable does not open when I start recording.

I speak about http://www.smartmeter.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the new version of Chromium has changed the path to its executable.

**Original path**

ChromiumPortable\App\Chromium\**x86**\Chrome.exe

**Path in 45.0.2431.0**

ChromiumPortable\App\Chromium\**64**\chrome.exe

In case you need a new version of Chromium, the recommended process is to install it **outside** of the SmartMeter folder and start it manually. You only need to add the Recorder plugin then. This is how you do it.

1. Start Chromium
2. Go to Settings / Extensions (or type **chrome://extensions/** in the address bar)
3. Drag & drop the Recorder plugin from *programs\ChromeExtras* onto Chromium

Run Recorder and use this instance of Chromium for recording.